# Red dot showing in review queue while on ban

Tags: discussion

Something I noticed while being temporarily banned from the review queue is that I would still be given the notification to tell me that there were reviews to be done.

[image]

It had caused a little confusion for myself thinking that perhaps the ban had been removed, sadly not. Perhaps it would be best to remove this red dot for those who are banned from reviewing questions/answers?

edit: To clarify my discussion point is simply on the notification, I'm not suggesting to remove the review queue as it's the best place to discover why exactly you were banned and for those unaware, if they're banned. My focus is on removing a notification which is completely useless for those on a ban and at time causes confusion.